# Python: Removing spaces from file output (stripping white space)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Part of this assignment is to strip any white space from a .txt that was written from another program. I think I have it down correctly, however the output from this code comes out as:

Chris

2

John

3

I'd like to remove the spaces between these. Am I missing something in the formatting section?

```
def main():
file = open("golf.txt", 'r')
line = file.readline()
while line != '':
    print(format(line))
    line = file.readline()
file.close()
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line you're reading in contains a newline character (`\n`), marking the end of the line. You'll need to remove those prior to printing. Something like:

```
print(format(line.rstrip()))
```

`rstrip` will remove all whitespaces by default without passing in an argument.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Could you also link me to a doc with formatting functions? I can't seem to find it, I'm new to coding and I've found the python doc to be kind of overwhelming to navigate. But perhaps I should just look harder.  Appreciate the help, friend! :)

Comment: In this case you shouldn't really need to use format since the rstrip is doing the work for you. Here's some links to help get you started. 
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#format   https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#formatspec

Answer (score 0):

```
 def main():
    file = open("golf.txt", 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line=='' or line=="/n":
            pass
        else:
            print(line)
    file.close()
main()
```